# How can I run groovy script as EASE script?

Tags: eclipse, groovy, scripting, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to run Groovy script file as "EASE Script" but nothing happens.

I know that **the Eclipse Advanced Scripting Environment** is originally written to use javascript. But javascript engine does't support multiline strings. So I need use groovy engine.

Is there some way to run *.groovy file as "EASE Script"?

Comment: Have you also installed the Groovy addon for EASE? https://github.com/eclipse-ease-addons/groovy

Comment: Yes, I've already installed the nightly build with groovy support. And I select groovy engine in a drop-down menu.

Comment: What happens when you right-click on the file and choose run as EASE script?

Comment: There is new page called "<path_to_my_script>.groovy" in the console window. That is all. Nothing happens.

Comment: The nightly builds of groovy are not up to data AFAIK, the plugins should be 0.3.0 version, but the built ones are 0.2.0. I am using most of this stuff by building locally (and editing as needed, it is a new project)

Comment: I recommend you checkout the code and build yourself, possibly sending an email to http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/ease-dev/ to notify/request nightly builds of groovy again. I know that the EASE devs would be very happy to have more people on board.

Comment: PS. I made sure that running a groovy script works from the current EASE repos.

Comment: Thanks for help. I do like you write. And I hope this will work.